# How to type double segment line in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ide

I want to type double segment line with shortcut keys in Xcode to cut two implementation code like this:

some code here.....

========= segement line ============

some code here....

which shortcut key combination can do this?
I mean the double line,not the code

Answer (score 1):

It's called code snippets.
You can create any snippet you want.

Just watch this video: [Create Xcode Code Snippets (iOS, Xcode 8)](https://youtu.be/toXKHJxM3N4)

**The list of the all available shortcuts is here:** [Xcode shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/MenuCommands/MenuCommands014.html)

You can create keyword and when autocomplition suggestions appear (it's enough to type 1-2 letters) just press Enter and it appears. Look at the pictures.

**1)** [image: Create snippet]

**2)** [image: Autocomplitions]

**3)** [image: line]

Comment: I want to type the “double line” with shortcut key ,not the code.

Comment: thanks, but I know Xcode has default shortcut keys,I used once and can not  remember now.

Comment: I added a link to the full list of Xcode shortcuts to my answer. You will probably find one which you need.

Comment: appreciate of your help